# SearchBar in UINavigationItem

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem

I added a search bar in the UINavigationItem using the following code:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[searchBar sizeToFit];
searchBar.delegate = self;
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
self.navigationItem.title = self.category.title;
[searchBar release];
```

but the result UI is like this:

[image]

How can I change the color of the search bar and make it the same with the background of the navigation bar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a UINavigationBar there is multiple ways to manipulate background color of it:

1. Set a tintColor property to a color that you need.
2. Follow proposed way of modification to apply custom gradient or other pattern image — http://leonov.co/2011/04/uinavigationbar-and-uitoolbar-customization-ultimate-solution/

For a search bar tintColor is also available. But in your case I suggest to inherit form UISearchBar and provide implementation as shown below to get rid from background drawing routine totally. In this case you will get search bar on an transparent toolbar and will and you will need to manage only UINavigationBar color.

```
//TransparentSearchBar.m

@interface TransparentSearchBar()
- (void)removeBackgroundView;
@end

@implementation TransparentSearchBar

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        [self removeBackgroundView];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder 
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if(self) {
        [self removeBackgroundView];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if(self) {
        [self removeBackgroundView];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)removeBackgroundView 
{
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString
             (@"UISearchBarBackground")])
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I inherited from UISearchBar with drawRect set to empty, and then use that class in my code. But the search bar is not transparent. I don't want to change the color of the navigation bar, I just want to make the search bar transparent so it can look better. This seems to be the solution, but it doesn't work.

Comment: My fault. I did it in analogue with UIToolbar but this didn't work. I wrote an alternate solution for UISearchBar You can find it in my answer.

Comment: Hi, Nikita, your solution works great on iOS 4.3. But when I run the app on an 4.1 iPhone recently, the search bar has a black background. Do you have any idea on this? Thanks.

Comment: `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` have to be added also in `removeBackgroundView`. It removes black background which appears when bar is being redrawn. Possibly it can help with 4.1, though I didn't check.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the documentation on UISearchBar it has the property "tintColor".
Set that to color of the navigation bar.

If you do not know the color of navigationbar, get the tintColor of navigationBar.

You might also want to lay with the "translucent" property of the searchbar. Might work better.